# Substring in Array c# (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this data

> Data : P  ,B  ,B P,P  ,T  ,P  ,P B

And i get it through this

```
for (int i = 0; i < gametable_history_list.Count; i++)
{
     newString[0] += gametable_history_list[i].r;
     newString[0] += ",";
}
string[] newChars = newString[0].Split(',');
foreach (string previousValue in newChars)
{}
```

this code `newString[0].Split(',').ToString().Substring(0,1);` doesn't work . I am pretty sure i am doing it wrong . Could someone point it out.

My expected result must be

> Data Earlier :  P ,B ,B P,P ,T ,P ,P B
>
> Data After Substring : P  ,B  ,B  ,P  ,T ,P  ,P

Comment: What do you mean by _"it doesn't work"_ ?

Comment: Please post your expected result!

Comment: `newString[0].Split(',').ToString().Substring(0,1);` where is this line in code?

Comment: .Split(',') returns an array but you are doing a ToString on it. Try .Split(',')[0].ToString().SubSring(0,1);

Comment: @GaurangDave its on the `string[] newChars = newString[0].Split(',');` this is what i tried `newString[0].Split(',').ToString().Substring(0,1);`

Comment: @TheGinxx009 What is your expected result ?

Comment: Have you tried breaking it down in steps - basic debugging - try printing out the result of _"newString[0].Split(',').ToString()"_

Comment: @SlavenTojić edited it

Comment: @PaulF wait sir

Comment: What is the logic behind removing the character? Is it a static string? I mean if you remove using index or substring, each time it will remove character from same position. Is that you want?

Comment: I need to remove those character sir because of a scoreboard i am doing . it is the rule

Comment: or Do you want to put space and comma (,) after every character?

Comment: Why don't you do the Substring operation when you are creating newString? _newString[0] += gametable_history_list[i].r.Substring(0,1);"_

Comment: @GaurangDave It has already spaces and Comma all i want to do sir is that get only the first char in every string i have.

Comment: @PaulF it gives me this error always `startIndex + length > this.length`

Comment: What type is the _"r"_ field in the _"newString[0] += gametable_history_list[i].r;"_ array

Comment: @PaulF it is `public string r`

Comment: You are first iterating over `gametable_history_list`, collecting the `.r` value into a string. Then you split that string again (note that the last item is empty because of the trailing comma). Why not use the that gametable_history_list directly?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you have some multi-char values (like "P B") in your `.r` that you want to reduce to single-char values ("P" in the example)?

Comment: @HansKesting yes

Comment: `newString[0].Split(',').ToString()` will always return `"System.String[]"` as `.Split` returns an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach (string previousValue in newChars)
{
   var result = previousValue.Substring(0,1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use this code:

```
var str = "P ,B ,B P,P ,T ,P ,P B";

var result = String.Join(",", str.Split(new string[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(r => r.Substring(0, r.IndexOf(' ') + 1)));
```

Result:

```
P ,B ,B ,P ,T ,P ,P
```

Without `Linq`:

```
var str = "P ,B ,B P,P ,T ,P ,P B";

var tempResult = str.Split(new string[] {","}, StringSplitOptions.None);

for (var a = 0; a < tempResult.Length; a++)
{
    tempResult[a] = tempResult[a].Substring(0, tempResult[a].IndexOf(' ') + 1);
}

var result = String.Join(",", tempResult);
```

Result:

```
P ,B ,B ,P ,T ,P ,P
```

Comment: couldn't find the .select sir though i imported system.linq

Comment: `using System.Linq`;

Comment: Yup did it `var result = String.Join(",", previousValue.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.None).SetProp/SetValue` only sir no `.Select`

Comment: string[] does not contain definition for 'Select'

Comment: @TheGinxx009, did you add `using System.Linq;`?

Comment: I can't use .Select sir because it is a string[] . Particularly I am using string[] not just string sir

Answer (score 2):

Following solution will work for you. I trim the space as well so if you need space then remove trimming. I did it in Console app.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = "P ,B ,B P,P ,T ,P ,P B";
    string result = string.Empty;

    string[] newChars = str.Split(',');

    foreach (string previousValue in newChars)
    {
        if (previousValue.Trim().Length > 1)
            result += previousValue.Trim().First().ToString().Trim() + " ,";
        else
            result += previousValue.Trim() + " ,";
    }

    result = result.Trim(',');

    Console.WriteLine(str);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Compact Solution using LINQ**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str = "P ,B ,B P,P ,T ,P ,P B";
    string result = string.Empty;

    string[] newChars = str.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();

    result = string.Join(" ,", newChars.Select(s => s.Length > 1 ? s.First().ToString() : s)); 

    Console.WriteLine(str);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
P ,B ,B P,P ,T ,P ,P B
P ,B ,B ,P ,T ,P ,P
```

Comment: `previousValue.Trim().First().ToString()` - you want to get rid of (leading) spaces *before* you get the first character

Comment: Why do you need an if statement - doesn't _"result += previousValue.Trim().First() + ",";"_ work regardless of string length (except empty - in which case use FirstOrDefault if an empty string should be in the list or just check length > 0)

Comment: I don't want to remove the spaces sir

Comment: @TheGinxx009: in that case either skip the Trim() or change "," to " ," to put the spaces back in

Comment: `result = result.Trim(',');` has an error . `Too many characters in character literal

Comment: @TheGinxx009 Check the update in answer. You can go for linq as well.

Comment: @TheGinxx009 I tested both code before putting here. No error when I run it.

Answer (score 2):

Short and precise answer( Use Linq):

```
 var data = "P, B, B P, P, T, P, P B";
 var output = String.Join(",",data.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim().Substring(0,1)));   

Output : P,B,B,P,T,P,P
```

No need of using Physical Loop.

Comment: i shared my answer sir though thank you . and one more thing i uses a string[] so i couldnt use `.Select` function